# Dynamic CSS ID with PHP

Tags: php, css, dynamic, selector

A newbie here. Trying to increment CSS ID selector with PHP.
Following the code I have

```
<?php
$thumbnails = get_post_meta($post->ID, "plans", false);
if ($thumbnails[0] != '') :?>
<div id="images-box">
<?php foreach($thumbnails as $thumb) {
    echo '<div class="holder">
        <div id="image-'. $id .'" class="image-lightbox">
            <span class="close"><a href="#">X</a></span>
            <img src="' . $thumb . '" alt="" />
            <a class="expand" href="#image-1"></a>
        </div>';
} ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

What I want is

```
<div id="image-1" class="image-lightbox">
<div id="image-2" class="image-lightbox">
<div id="image-3" class="image-lightbox">
```

I tried with many options that were answered here (http://codepad.org/OHuTxQPI) but couldn't get it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add `$id=1;` and `$id++;` in your code.

```
<?php 
$id = 1;
foreach($thumbnails as $thumb) {
echo '<div class="holder">
    <div id="image-'. $id .'" class="image-lightbox">
        <span class="close"><a href="#">X</a></span>
        <img src="' . $thumb . '" alt="" />
        <a class="expand" href="#image-1"></a>
    </div>';
$id++;
} ?>
```

Edited: `$id=1;` should be used if you want to start from `id='image-1'`.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `$id` as a counter but don't actually define or increment anywehre.

```
<?php
$thumbnails = get_post_meta($post->ID, "plans", false);
if ($thumbnails[0] != '') :?>
<div id="images-box">
<?php 
$id = 0; 
foreach($thumbnails as $thumb) {
    echo '<div class="holder">
        <div id="image-'. $id .'" class="image-lightbox">
            <span class="close"><a href="#">X</a></span>
            <img src="' . $thumb . '" alt="" />
            <a class="expand" href="#image-1"></a>
        </div>';
$id++;
} ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: The output was <div id="image-1098"> <div id="image-1099"> How can I get this as 1,2,3

Comment: That's odd considering you set $id = 0. Is that line of code in the same place as in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the rest, I'm using a straight `for()` loop instead of `foreach()` to give more control (ok it's really just cuz I'm OCD and like to use `$i`).

### [Here's the demo](http://codepad.org/2waeVzhc)

### PHP:

```
<?php
  $thumbnails = array(0 => array('thumb' => 'image.jpg'), 1 => array('thumb' => 'image2.jpg'));
// $thumbnails = get_post_meta($post->ID, "plans", false);
  if (isset($thumbnails)): ?>
<div id="images-box">
<?php 
  $i = 0;
  $thumbs = count($thumbnails);
  for($i;$i < $thumbs;$i++) { ?>

<div class="holder">
  <div id="image-<?php print $i; ?>" class="image-lightbox">
    <span class="close"><a href="#">X</a></span>
    <img src="<?php print $thumbnails[$i]['thumb']; ?>" alt="" />
    <a class="expand" href="#image-<?php print $i; ?>"></a>
  </div>
<?php }; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

### HTML output:

```
<div id="images-box">

<div class="holder">
  <div id="image-0" class="image-lightbox">
    <span class="close"><a href="#">X</a></span>
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="" />
    <a class="expand" href="#image-0"></a>
  </div>

<div class="holder">
  <div id="image-1" class="image-lightbox">
    <span class="close"><a href="#">X</a></span>
    <img src="image2.jpg" alt="" />
    <a class="expand" href="#image-1"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Counter for `$id` as told by John or use `$id` as index for `foreach` loop as below.

```
<?php
$thumbnails = get_post_meta($post->ID, "plans", false);
if ($thumbnails[0] != '') :?>
<div id="images-box">
<?php foreach($thumbnails as $id=> $thumb) {
    echo '<div class="holder">
        <div id="image-'. $id .'" class="image-lightbox">
            <span class="close"><a href="#">X</a></span>
            <img src="' . $thumb . '" alt="" />
            <a class="expand" href="#image-1"></a>
        </div>';
} ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```